# Result Difference in Stanford NER tagger NLTK (python) vs JAVA

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using both python and java to run the Stanford NER tagger but I am seeing the difference in the results.

For example, when I input the sentence "Involved in all aspects of data modeling using ERwin as the primary software for this.",

JAVA Result:

```
"ERwin": "PERSON"
```

Python Result:

```
In [6]: NERTagger.tag("Involved in all aspects of data modeling using ERwin as the primary software for this.".split())
Out [6]:[(u'Involved', u'O'),
 (u'in', u'O'),
 (u'all', u'O'),
 (u'aspects', u'O'),
 (u'of', u'O'),
 (u'data', u'O'),
 (u'modeling', u'O'),
 (u'using', u'O'),
 (u'ERwin', u'O'),
 (u'as', u'O'),
 (u'the', u'O'),
 (u'primary', u'O'),
 (u'software', u'O'),
 (u'for', u'O'),
 (u'this.', u'O')]
```

Python nltk wrapper can't catch "ERwin" as PERSON.

What's interesting here is both Python and Java uses the same trained data (english.all.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz) released in 2015-04-20.

My ultimate goal is to make python work in the same way Java does.

I'm looking at StanfordNERTagger in nltk.tag to see if there's anything I can modify. Below is the wrapper code:

```
class StanfordNERTagger(StanfordTagger):
"""
A class for Named-Entity Tagging with Stanford Tagger. The input is the paths to:

- a model trained on training data
- (optionally) the path to the stanford tagger jar file. If not specified here,
  then this jar file must be specified in the CLASSPATH envinroment variable.
- (optionally) the encoding of the training data (default: UTF-8)

Example:

    >>> from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
    >>> st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz') # doctest: +SKIP
    >>> st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split()) # doctest: +SKIP
    [('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'),
     ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'),
     ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'LOCATION')]
"""

_SEPARATOR = '/'
_JAR = 'stanford-ner.jar'
_FORMAT = 'slashTags'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StanfordNERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

@property
def _cmd(self):
    # Adding -tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer -tokenizerOptions tokenizeNLs=false for not using stanford Tokenizer  
    return ['edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier',
            '-loadClassifier', self._stanford_model, '-textFile',
            self._input_file_path, '-outputFormat', self._FORMAT, '-tokenizerFactory', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer', '-tokenizerOptions','\"tokenizeNLs=false\"']

def parse_output(self, text, sentences):
    if self._FORMAT == 'slashTags':
        # Joint together to a big list    
        tagged_sentences = []
        for tagged_sentence in text.strip().split("\n"):
            for tagged_word in tagged_sentence.strip().split():
                word_tags = tagged_word.strip().split(self._SEPARATOR)
                tagged_sentences.append((''.join(word_tags[:-1]), word_tags[-1]))

        # Separate it according to the input
        result = []
        start = 0 
        for sent in sentences:
            result.append(tagged_sentences[start:start + len(sent)])
            start += len(sent);
        return result 

    raise NotImplementedError
```

Or, if it's because of using different Classifier (In java code, it seems to use AbstractSequenceClassifier, on the other hand, python nltk wrapper uses the CRFClassifier.) is there a way that I can use AbstractSequenceClassifier in python wrapper?

Comment: Using CoreNLP is the way to go for flexible use of Stanford tools with python interface. But let me try whether I can hack our way out in this, after breakfast though ;)

Comment: What is the Java command you've ran? Did you run it on the command line?

Comment: did Gabor Angeli's solution actually work or not?

Comment: @Toussaint they updated the maxAdditionalKnownLCWords to 0 but I am still get different results.

Comment: Have you succeeded to fix the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `maxAdditionalKnownLCWords` to 0 in the properties file (or command line) for CoreNLP, and if possible for NLTK as well. This disables an option which allows the NER system to learn from test-time data a little bit, which could cause occasional mildly different results.

Comment: may I know how to set maxAdditionalKnownLCWords ?

Comment: @Gabor Can you explain a bit on this?

Comment: @Gabor Can you please help me to set maxAdditionalKnownLCWords ?